I can't launch Delayedjob as soon as my Rails server starts
I cannot launch DelayedJob as soon as I start my Rails application on my VPS on Ubuntu 22.04.
I have one project with Rails 7.1.2 (Ruby 3.0.0) which start with Passenger on apache2:
PassengerRuby /opt/rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby
Problem: I have tried several solutions to launch it and it succeeds, but once it has launched all the remaining jobs, it exits automatically, but I would like it to be constantly open.
I tried with Crontab with @reboot (with whenever gem):
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/extranet-rails/durbano-rails && RAILS_ENV=production /opt/rbenv/shims/bundle exec rake delayed_jobs:start --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
My delayed_jobs:start task:
namespace :delayed_jobs do
  desc 'Start delayed jobs'
  task start: :environment do
    system("/opt/rbenv/shims/bundle /var/www/extranet-rails/durbano-rails/bin/delayed_job start")
  end
end

I tried with service and exec script
[Unit]
Description=Delayed Job Workers
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="RAILS_ENV=production"
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/extranet-rails/durbano-rails
ExecStart=/var/www/extranet-rails/durbano-rails/script.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=delayed_job

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

script.sh (with Foreman):
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/extranet-rails/durbano-rails
export RAILS_ENV=production


echo "Starting foreman..." >> myapp.log 2>&1
/opt/rbenv/shims/foreman start >> myapp.log 2>&1
echo "Foreman terminated with exit code $?" >> myapp.log 2>&1

Procfile (Foreman):
delayed: /opt/rbenv/shims/bundle exec bin/delayed_job start

For all situations, I don't have any errors but it always quits on its own...

Note that if I run exactly the same command in my process, DelayedJob remains fine open even if there are no jobs to process.

Have you tried Restart=Always and put the service file in systemd/system?

Yes I did it but as a result the service keeps stopping and restarting so that fixes the problem but I don't think it's the right solution because it impacts the performance of the server in my opinion :(

The other thing i'd try is to change ExecStart to ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec bin/delayed_job start

This will only shift the problem given that I have several versions of Ruby and each project has its DJ problem... I just need a way to launch a command in cron/service as if I were launching it myself from my console, since in this case it works well...
